# Puedo crear un .war con Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Tengo un proyecto en Maven al cual quiero generar un .war para ejecutar en mi Apache Tomcat alojado en Docker, pero he probado a meter este plugin en el pom.xml y no me genera nada excepto el .jar en la carpeta de /target:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/com/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>ROOT</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

También tengo un paquete, así que me estructura de directorios principal es esta:

src/com/proyecto/clinicadentista

Mucho menos me genera el .war en la carpeta src/com/webapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el mismo POM tienes que indicarle que el empaquetado es como WAR, muy al comienzo.

```
<artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
    ...
```

Ya después, que uses un plug-in para controlar cieeertos comportamientos del empaquetado, eso es diferente :)

Comment: Gracias, y cómo compruebo que funciona en mi Tomcat? Lo tengo instalado en el Escritorio dentro de una carpeta web que contiene las carpetas de instalación de Tomcat (ROOT, host-manager etc.) Uso la dirección http://localhost:8081/

Comment: Un war se despliega poniéndolo en la carpeta webapps del tomcat. O usando la interfaz de administración, si es que la tienes ya configurada.